# Creating a scatterplot for a grouped pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a Pandas DataFrame where I want to group by a certain column. Afterwards, I want to make a scatterplot of this grouped dataframe. However if I do so I get an error, because the column I group by is nog recognized.

```
# Data loading, processing and for more
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Visualization
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# set seaborn style because it prettier
sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df2 = df.groupby(['A']).agg({'D':sum})
df2.plot.scatter(x='A', y='D')
```

How would I create such a scatterplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either not set `A` as index in `groupby`:

```
# notice the difference `sum` and `'sum'`
# the later is vectorized
df2 = df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False).agg({'D':'sum'})

df2.plot.scatter(x='A', y='D')
```

Or you can keep your code and use `plt.scatter`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['A']).agg({'D':'sum'})
plt.scatter(df2.index, df2['D'])
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to reset the index after `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Visualization
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# set seaborn style because it prettier
sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df2 = df.groupby(['A']).agg({'D':sum})
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.plot.scatter(x='A', y='D')
```

When groupby operation is performed, by default the column on which groupby is done becomes the index. In above case after groupby, if you check the df2, its structure would be like this:

```
In [2]: df2                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[2]: 
      D
A      
0   180
1    29
2    52
3    39
4    91
..  ...
93   56
94   17
96   47
98  125
99  214

[61 rows x 1 columns]
```

To access the column A, you would need to use `reset_index` to make index as a separate column.

Comment: you could also pass `as_index=False` to your groupby and avoid the need to reset in the index. Something like `ax = f.groupby(['A'], as_index=False).agg({'D':sum}).plot.scatter(x='A', y= 'D')`